# trying to connect to a openvpn config file and test my connection using python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, connection, openvpn

I have a lots of `.ovpn` openvpn config file that I need to connect and test my connection to them.
I have managed to connect to them using `subprocess`

but the problem is that when I run the code, Python executes the openvpn connection command halfway and executes the following commands before connecting the system to vpn.
And when I use `subprocess.Popen().wait()`, when the system connects to the vpn, it no longer closes the shell and the code gets stuck there.
I don't know how to fix.
Here is my code :

```
result = {"successful": [], "failed": []}
configs = os.listdir(Path('configs')) # load config files
for config in configs:
    # connect to vpn
    subprocess.Popen(f'echo pass | sudo -S openvpn --config configs/{config} --auth-user-pass pass.txt', shell=True).wait() 
    newip = check_ip(session)
    if newip in ips:
        result["failed"].append({config: newip})
    else:
        result["successful"].append({config: newip})
        ips.append(newip)
    # killing the connection
    subprocess.Popen('echo pass | sudo -S killall openvpn', shell=True)
    print('sleeping for 30')
    time.sleep(30)
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'openvpn', "filename"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        print (output.strip())
        if "Initialization Sequence Completed" in str(output):
            print("Do something if it succeed")
        else if "Failed or something":
            print("Do something if it fails")
 
retval = process.poll()
```

It will launch the vpn file, wait for some kind of str - in this case "Initialization Sequence Completed", and then run some code. :)

Comment: this method is not working. the process only returns one line.